# Solid Objects in HTML5 Canvas game - can't walk along top

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

As the title suggests, I'm having trouble creating a solid object for my HTML5 canvas game.

So far I can stop the player walking into the left and right of the box, and stop it jumping up to the box (the player hits the bottom of the box and falls down) but I can't seem to get the player to stand/walk along the top, it just continuously floats up, or down (depending on the + or - number I give it to stop it from going into the box.)

The player also needs to be able to jump up/off when on the top of the object.

Here's the bit of code I've got for this so far:

```
function collides(player, platform){                 

                //return !(player.x > platform.x + platform.width || player.x + player.width  < platform.x || player.y > platform.y + platform.height || player.y + player.height < platform.y);
                if(player.x + player.width > platform.x && !(player.x > platform.x + platform.width) && !(player.y + player.height < platform.y) && !(player.y > platform.y + platform.height)){
                    player.velocity_x = -1;
                }
                if(player.x < platform.x + platform.width && !(player.x < platform.x)  && !(player.y + player.height < platform.y) && !(player.y > platform.y + platform.height)){
                    player.velocity_x = 1;
                }
                if(player.y + player.height < platform.y && player.x + player.width > platform.x && player.x < platform.x + platform.width && (player.y < platform.y + platform.height)){
                   //player.y = platform.y -41;
                    player.velocity_y = -1;
                   //jumping = false;
                }
                if(player.y < platform.y + platform.height && player.x + player.width > platform.x && player.x < platform.x + platform.width && !(player.y + player.height < platform.y)){
                    player.velocity_y = 1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, which direction are you axis pointing? Is it positive y down or positive y up? I'm guessing positive x is to the right

Comment: @TheCrzyMan Positive y is going down and yeah, positive X is to the right

Comment: you should handle a fifth case : the 'hero' is at the right distance of the platform, and its y velocity is null. (unless there's a jump).

Comment: Next question. Why is `jumping = false` quoted out? Does it not serve the purpose of telling some sort of physics logic that it shouldn't fall?

Comment: @GameAlchemist could you tell me more about this 5th case and what should be done if it is met?

Comment: @TheCrzyMan That just stops the player when they = the force of gravity, so instead of just going up continuously it falls when it meets the force of gravity

Comment: that would be something like : x is ok && Math.abs(player.y + player.height - platform.y) < some threshold (1 or 2 most probably).

Comment: if you make a small fiddle with what you have i'll make it work.

Comment: @GameAlchemist ok here we are http://jsfiddle.net/p36Uf/ I've been playing with it since earlier and can now stay on top of a block providing I press the up key(jump), but it now also jumps through the bottom... not sure if i've broken it more, or made it better D:

Comment: @GameAlchemist http://jsfiddle.net/NrLz9/ ok looks like I've fixed the above problem, however it now doesn't move, I've looked online for this problem and it appears that I can't move because I'm not setting my X velocity to > 0 after setting it to 0, so just finding out where i've done that and how I can fix it now

Comment: @GameAlchemist sorry, that link just took you back to the first one http://jsfiddle.net/4gSg5/1/